# How to display multiple html in same page on flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I'm trying to create an app where I can click at a link/button in a page displayed in one column, and exhibit an html in the other column without reloading the page. I'm also trying to do that in a way that I can have multiple links/buttons and if I click in a different link it changes the display.

So far I was doing that by redrawing the whole page on plot html, but it is slow. My view html looks like that

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--// JQuery Reference, If you have added jQuery reference in your master page then ignore, 
// else include this too with the below reference
-->

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="static/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();
    });
</script>



</head>
<body>

  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">

    <table id="table_id" 

    class="">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> <a href="javascript:plot1('par1', 'par2', 'par3');">Jill </a></td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:plot2('par1', 'par2', 'par3');">Eve </a</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();
        });
    </script>

  </div>
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#bbb;" id="targetColumn1">
    <script>
    function plot1(par1, par2, par3) {
        var arr = ['/plot1?par1=', par1, '&par2=', par2, '&par3=',  par3];
        var urlcpar = arr.join('');
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: urlcpar,
          success: function(response) {
               $("#targetColumn1").html(response);
          },
         });
    }
    </script>


  </div>
  <div class="column3" style="background-color:#bbb;" id="targetColumn2" >
    <script>
    function plot2(par1, par2, par3) {
        var arr = ['/plot2?par1=', par1, '&par2=', par2, '&par3=',  par3];
        var urlcpar = arr.join('');
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: urlcpar,
          success: function(response) {
               $("#targetColumn2").html(response);
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
              //Do Something to handle error
          }
         });
    }
    </script>



  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

my css looks like

```
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 100.0%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50.0%; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50.0%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50.0%; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column3 {
    float: right;
    width: 50.0%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50.0%; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}



/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

My plot html 1 looks like

```
{{ html|safe }}
```

My plot html 2 looks like

```
{{ plot|safe }}
```

My app is something like this, where I have the two html that I want to display in the same page

```
from flask import * 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# IF CHANGE THE ROUTE HERE FOR '/<eventid>' works 
@app.route('/view/<eventid>')
def page_view(eventid):
    global event
    event = eventid
    print(event)
    return render_template('view.html')

@app.route("/plot1")
def plot1():
    par1 = str(request.args.get('par1'))
    par2 = str(request.args.get('par2'))
    par3 = str(request.args.get('par3'))

    fname = './static/'+event
    if not os.path.exists(fname):
        os.mkdir(fname)

    f = open(fname+'/example.html', 'w+')
    f.write('<HTML><p> \
            <body>' \
          +par1+par2+par3+'</p> \
          <img src="./plot/test.png"> \
          </body> </HTML>')
    f.close() 

    #fl = fname+'/example.html'
    #fl = 'http://visjs.org/examples/network/nodeStyles/images.html' 
    fl = fname+'/Network _ Images.html'
    return render_template('plot1.html', html='<object width="100%" height="100%" data=\"'+fl+'\"></object>')


@app.route("/plot2")
def plot2():
    par1 = str(request.args.get('par1'))
    par2 = str(request.args.get('par2'))
    par3 = str(request.args.get('par3'))

    fname = './static/'+event
    if not os.path.exists(fname):
        os.mkdir(fname)

    fname = fname+'/plot/' 
    if not os.path.exists(fname):
        os.mkdir(fname)

    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
    plt.plot(t, s)

    plt.xlabel('time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
    plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(fname+"/test.png")

    fl = fname+'/test.png'
    return render_template('plot2.html', plot='<img src=\"'+fl+'\">')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess... in case you are trying to have multiple plots on one page and you want them to be somehow connected with each other, you probably want to have a look at [Plotly Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/), which is also build on top of flask.

Here is an [example](https://plot.ly/dash/gallery/live-wind-data/)

Comment: have you considered using frames?

Comment: I thought about that, but I saw it was not supported in html5 anymore, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX to fetch content from the server and display that content in the second column. Below is a sample application illustrating this concept:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


@app.route('/')
def page_view():
    return render_template('view.html')


@app.route('/plot')
def plot():
    return render_template('plot.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**templates/view.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("a.loadPlot").click(function() {

         args = $(this).data('args');

         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             data: args,
             url: "{{ url_for('plot') }}",
             success: function(data) {
                 $('#targetColumn').html(data)
             }
       });

     });

 });

</script>


<style>
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <a href="#" class="loadPlot" data-args='{"par1": 1, "par2": 4, "par3": 10}'>Plot 1</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="loadPlot" data-args='{"par1": 5, "par2": 3, "par3": 5}'>Plot 2</a><br />
      <a href="#" class="loadPlot" data-args='{"par1": 10, "par2": 9, "par3": 1}'>Plot 3</a><br />
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;" id="targetColumn">

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**templates/plot.html**

```
Plot with args: <br /><br/ >

<ul>
    {% for a in request.args %}
        <li>{{ a }} - {{ request.args[a] }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, I think your answer is kind of what I was looking for. I'm using `href='javascript:showColum(par1, ..., parN)'` and then I format the url as `plot?par1=x&...&parN=xN` in a similar ajax call, but then when I do `$("#targetColumn").html(data)` the call works, I generate a png and its html but it return an url `view/something` and I don't understand why. If I replace `href:javascript:` by your id approach, how can I use parameters?

Comment: When you say "it return an url view/something" what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: When I inspect the print information from flask, on terminal, I can see that the calls where correctly formatted like I can see `/plot?par1=x...` and then I also see `"GET /view/static/data HTTP/1.1" 404` and in the browser I also see that the resource was not found.

Comment: I'm now breaking my app in pieces to create a small reproducible example and see where the error is.

Comment: I'd say that request is coming from somewhere in your plotly code, hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you might pass parameters to the AJAX call

Comment: Hi @Matt I just updated the question with a reproducible example. It now works as I expect, if I change the `/view/<eventid>` route to `/<eventid>`, but I don't understand why.  with the view route I have the error `GET /view/static/aaaa/plot//test.png HTTP/1.1" 404` when loading a html/png on static. That also happens if try to load a png inside vis js (example in the code) because it somehow re-routes and I don't get how it happens. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is not short, and I cannot accomplish it fully with just parts of code that you've provided, but I can give you some guidance so you can continue.

Change your /PLOT route to return json instead of rendering template.

```
@app.route('/plot')
def plot():
    ...
    return flask.jsonify(jsongraph)
```

Then you need to add all needed libraries to your first html, so include `plotly` js. After that you need to add ajax calls instead of links to button:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <span id="link">link text</span>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;" id="target">
    <!-- DISPLAY SOMETHING HERE -->
</div>
```

and add something like (example in jQuery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.get('/ploty', function(data){
       ...
       Plotly.plot(..., graph.data, graph.layout);
       ...
   });
});
</script>
```

Idk how plotly works exactly, but you need to provide to it id of `target` div somehow. Also maybe you need to clear previous content of div.